# Admin and Front End Store Speed Issue

Tags: coldfusion

I have ColdFusion sites for both admin and front end E commerce, I have more number of schedulers running for admin maintenance which are causing my front end store to become very slow.
Can someone help me in setting up the admin / front end sites, so that front end store loads quickly irrespective of scheduled jobs?

Comment: Schedule them for off peak hours.

Comment: You may also look into query caching if you haven't already. Depending on how your site is set up this could help tremendously.

Comment: What scheduled jobs are using up resources? Follow the above suggestions, but I'd also suggest figuring out where the bottleneck is and if something can be done to fix it.

Comment: You have sites for each, but are you running them on independent instances of ColdFusion (enterprise edition)? If you do that, you can have the admin processes run as they do now, without impacting the performance of the instance running the ecommerce app. The only latency at that point would be related to the database, but you could scale that accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the CF enterprise edition, you can manage the admin / front end sites by creating multiple instances/cluster environments.

The idea is to:

- Create two ColdFusion instances and bind admin / front end to
  different instances

  - Create a cluster with two instances and bind to admin and create another instance for front end (if the scheduled jobs have more load
    than the front end)

For more detailed info check here: 
https://www.itlandmark.com/blog/clustering-for-load-balancing-and-failover-using-coldfusion-10/